# Strip multiple extensions using basename() in php

Tags: php, arrays, function, foreach

I want to disappear extension of more than one.

```
 if (!empty($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'])){
    foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name) {
    $nama_files= $_FILES['files']['name'][$key];

    $ack= rand(1,99);
    $nama_files = $ack.$nama_files; 
    $dir_upload = "../../../img_galeri/";
    $file_upload = $dir_upload . $nama_files;
    move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $file_upload);

   $title= basename($nama_files,".jpg") ;
```

I want to make all the images extension `(.jpg .png .gif)` disappeared and did not participate stored in the title picture.

I've tried to use like this, but it doesn't run and doesn't work

```
$title= basename($nama_files,".jpg,png,gif,jpex,x-png") ;
```

can anyone help me solve to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the last statement to this:

```
$title= basename($nama_files);
$pos = strrpos($title, '.');
if($pos !== false)
{
   $ext = substr($title, $pos+1);
   if($ext === 'jpg' ||
      $ext === 'png' ||
      $ext === 'gif' ||
      $ext === 'jpex' ||
      $ext === 'x-png')
   {
      $title = substr($title,0,$pos);
   }


}
```

I hope this solves your problem

Answer (score 1):

If your version of `php` `>=` `php 5.2.x` You can use [`pathinfo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) to grab just the name of the file without its extension.

```
$info = pathinfo('/www/img_galeri/asdf.jpg');
$onlyname = $info['filename']; // 'asdf'
```